# Iterating over collections.defaultdict(list)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import itertools
import collections

def get_pairs(some_list, limit):
    min = 2
    pair_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for x in range(min, limit+1):
        pair_dict[x].append(list(itertools.combinations(some_list, x)))

    return pair_dict

z = get_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4], 4)
for key, value in z.items():
    print("Key: {}", "Value: {}".format(key, value))

Output:
Key: {} Value: 2
Key: {} Value: 3
Key: {} Value: 4
```

I was expecting key to come as 2, 3, 4 and value to be a list.
Something like below

```
{
 2: [[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]], 
 3: [[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]], 
 4: [[(1, 2, 3, 4)]]
}
```

What is wrong with my code or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print` statement is just messed up. Change it to:

```
print("Key: {}, Value: {}".format(key, value))
```

Your original

```
print("Key: {}", "Value: {}".format(key, value))
```

is printing the literal string `"Key: {}"` (without any formatting), followed by the formatted string `"Value: {}".format(key, value)` which uses the first argument `key` to fill its only placeholder.

It is easy to get fooled here with the placeholder `"{}"` looking like an empty `dict` and all =)